# Deactivate menu opening when pressing Alt in sublime

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I use alt + ijkl as arrow keys to move my cursor when I am coding. However in Sublime text when you press alt, it opens the upper left menu, and it sometimes messes up my shortcuts. Is there any way to deactivate that ? Haven't found it in "preferences -> keybinds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but not in Sublime Text 3; only Sublime Text 4, which introduces the following setting (shown here with default value):

```json
    // When false, disables alt-tapping revealing the menu when hidden on Linux
    // and Windows. Does not affect auto hiding or toggling the menu through
    // the command palette.
    "reveal_menu": true,
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I actually use Sublime Text 4, I just didn't find the tag for it, so it gaslighted me into thinking I was using Sublime Text 3. This is perfect !